# VBScript to have a local user change password at next logon?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get a script to run for a local user while logged in to have there user account require them to change their password once they log of then log back in. I have about 40 different users that all have there own local internet connection so i don't have active directory for these computers where i can easily set this. I want to be able to push out a script through remote access that will preform this action (having to reset their password).

The user account name that I am trying to run the script for is called: Ual-Lab-Tech
The script I am running is:

```
' Bind to local user object.  
Set objUser = GetObject("Ual-Lab-Tech")

' Require password change at next logon.  
objUser.PasswordExpired = 1  
objUser.SetInfo
```

However when I run the script I am getting an error:

```
Script:  C:\\Users\UAL-Lab-Tech\Desktop\change password at logon.vbs  
Line:   2  
Char:   1  
Error:  Invalid syntax  
Code:   800401E4  
Source   (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will find a working sample [here](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/localusers/):

```
strComputer = "atl-win2k-01"
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/kenmyer ")
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: And it gave me this error:  The Network Path was not found. Code: 80070035

Comment: I did change the computer name and the user from the following but it still did not work. This script is run within the users account correct? For example if i was logged into kenmyer account i would run this script in here?

Comment: Also the accounts are not admin accounts i dont know if this makes a difference or not?

Comment: @Josh: Please recopy, the original version had an additional blank in the path, the issue is now fixed.

Comment: ok, so i tried that and now im getting Error: Group name could not be found. Code 800708AC

Comment: I checked my spelling of the computer name and user name at it is correct.... It says its on line 2 char 1

Comment: ok so i removed another space after the user so instead of kenmyer " its now kenmyer"

Comment: and i am getting a access is denied error 800700005  Active Directory is the source.

Answer (score 0):

The sample above is for local accounts. 
For an AD account you have to use ADSI like this:

```
Set objUser = GetObject ("LDAP://CN=username,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local")
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: Ok well im not using Active Directory.